# How to disable Edit/Hide/Delete in TCA for TYPO3 Extbase Domain Model?

Tags: typo3, readonly, domain-model

As the title already says, I want to make a specific Extbase domain-model completely "read only" .. It is a custom Log-Entry model that shall be viewable but must not be modified via backend (they are being generated during certain controller actions).
I do not use the TYPO3 log system intentionally, because I want to have a separate log with its own db-table etc.
I do know about the readOnly property for columns, but I`d like to disable any modification-functions in the list view also.
Thanks in advance, Oliver

Comment: What kind of modification-functions in the list view do you mean, which can not be disabled with 'readOnly'?

Comment: I want to completely disable ANY functions that are not list/show. So no record addition,editing/deletion shall be possible via backend.

Comment: If so, what about write your own backend modul, where you can list/show all entries as you want? Then you can hide your table in list modul with
'mod.web_list.table.tx_myext_domain_model_mytable.hideTable = 1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not only option "readOnly" for columns, this option can also be set for the whole table:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['yourTable']['ctrl']['readOnly'] = 1;
```

Have a look at EXT:static_info_tables, the records from this extension are not editable.

Comment: THIS is really helpful. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Works like a charm. In TYPO3 8: It's just irritating that those records still can be opened for editing, but there is no way to save. There are also deleted or copy buttons in the list module which can be clicked but having no function.

Comment: Is there any way to make only readonly particular extenion/tt_content record or Editlock?